# How to append a list of lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I want to append a list of list like this : `append(Ls,L)` ,the first element of L is the first element of the first list in Ls,the second element of L is the first element of the second list in Ls, and so on for all the lists in Ls. After this, the next element of L is the second element of the first list in Ls, and so on, until two elements have been taken from all the lists in Ls. After this, come the third elements of all the lists in Ls, and so on, until all the elements of all the lists in Ls are included in L.

forexample:
I have a list `Ls=[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]`
and want to get this `L=[a,c,e,b,d,f]`
or I have `Ls=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` and I want to get `L=[1,4,2,5,3,6]`

Comment: Use `append/2`, or check out its definition in the Prolog library. `append/2` is definitely a lot cleaner than `flatten/2`, so I highly recommend to use `append/2` when you want the things you describe.

Comment: `append([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],L)`. we get `L=[1,2,3,4,5,6]` not `L=[1,4,2,5,3,6]`

Comment: Ah I see. I still recommend you check out the definition of `append/2`, it may help you to get more familiar with lists of lists.

Comment: You are not appending them, you are "zipping" them. Do all lists have to be of the same length for this to work?

Comment: @Boris: zipping and concatenating

Comment: oh, yes ,the length of thses lists are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to practise implementing recursive predicates, you could proceed like this using [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg):

```
matrix_transposed_items(Mss,Xs) :-
   notlonger_than(Mss,Xs),
   phrase(matrix_tconcat(Mss),Xs).

matrix_tconcat([]) --> [].
matrix_tconcat([Cs|Css]) -->
   row_rows_rest_(Cs,Css,Mss),
   matrix_tconcat(Mss).

row_rows_rest_([],Css,[]) --> 
   { emptylists(Css) }.
row_rows_rest_([X|Xs],Xss,[Xs|Mss]) -->
   [X],
   nonemptyrows_rest(Xss,Mss).

nonemptyrows_rest([],[]) --> [].
nonemptyrows_rest([[X|Xs]|Xss],[Xs|Mss]) -->
   [X],
   nonemptyrows_rest(Xss,Mss).
```

Above code is based on three auxiliary predicates which can be defined like this:

```
nil_or_cons([]).
nil_or_cons([_|_]).

notlonger_than([],Bs) :-
   nil_or_cons(Bs).
notlonger_than([_|As],[_|Bs]) :-
   notlonger_than(As,Bs).

emptylists([]).
emptylists([[]|Xs]) :-
   emptylists(Xs).
```

Let's run some queries!  First, we use some quadratic matrix:

```
?- matrix_transposed_items([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],Xs).
Xs = [1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9].                            % succeeds deterministically
```

Next, the non-quadratic use-cases the OP gave:

```
?- matrix_transposed_items([[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]],Ls).
Ls = [a,c,e,b,d,f].                                  % succeeds deterministically

?- matrix_transposed_items([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],Ls).
Ls = [1,4,2,5,3,6].                                  % succeeds deterministically
```

Let's try going the "other direction", too!

```
?- matrix_transposed_items(Mss,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]).
  Mss = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]]
; Mss = [[1,3,5,7,9],[2,4,6,8,10]]
; Mss = [[1,6],[2,7],[3,8],[4,9],[5,10]]
; Mss = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10]]
; false.                                             % terminates universally
```

Comment: Nice approach, +1! `emptylists(Ls)` is just: `maplist(=([]), Ls)`.

Comment: @mat. Guess what my initial version looked like:)

Comment: @mat. It's been a while since I last posted an answer that uses no meta-predicates whatsoever;)  Well, except for `phrase/2`, of course.

Comment: @mat. Also, I wanted to do some runtime measurements of the various proposed answers running on different Prolog processors.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SWI-Prolog, you can proceed like this:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd),[transpose/2]).
true.
```

Here's the sample query the OP gave:

```
?- Mss=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], transpose(Mss,Tss), append(Tss,Xs).
Mss = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]], Tss = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]], Xs = [1,4,2,5,3,6].
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a relational solution, but illustrates a recursive approach to the problem:

```
zipflat(Lists, Result) :-
    zipflat_aux(Lists, ResultLists),
    append(ResultLists, Result).

zipflat_aux(Lists, [Heads|ZipTails]) :-
    maplist(head_tail, Lists, Heads, Tails),
    zipflat_aux(Tails, ZipTails), !.
zipflat_aux([[]|_], []).

head_tail([H|T], H, T).
```

The cut (`!`) eliminates the unneeded choice point.

Answer (score 0):

since append/2 has a different meaning, let's call it zip/2

```
zip([A|As], Zip) :-
    findall(Es, (   nth1(P, A, _),
            findall(E, (member(L, [A|As]), nth1(P, L, E)), Es)
    ), Ts), append(Ts, Zip) /*flatten(Ts, Zip)*/ .
```